# error when I moved my drupal website

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I'm a newbie in drupal. I have a website built with drupal 6, I moved it to another server, but the website is not working correctly I think it is a theme path problem.

the errors:
1- Notice: Undefined index: website_theme in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\website_drupal\includes\theme.inc on line 71

2- Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\website_drupal\includes\theme.inc on line 104

3- Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\website_drupal\includes\theme.inc on line 231

Error image:
http://i39.tinypic.com/20fp7hw.png

I don't know how to fix this errors

Answer (score 0):

1) Can you show source code (aroud line 71) of this file:

```
C:\Program Files\wamp\www\website_drupal\includes\theme.inc
```

2) that file is available to this directory?

3) Can you enter to admnistration panel? /admin

Comment: 1- line 71
  $base_theme = array();
  $ancestor = $theme;
  while ($ancestor && isset($themes[$ancestor]->base_theme)) {
    $base_theme[] = $new_base_theme = $themes[$themes[$ancestor]->base_theme];
    $ancestor = $themes[$ancestor]->base_theme;
  }

_init_theme($themes[$theme], array_reverse($base_theme));

2- the file is available yes

3- Yes, I can enter the administration panel

Comment: check file system settings: /admin/settings/file-system. Try to replace "/" to "\". And try to select other site's theme (some standart them). I think that problem in file template.php in your custom them or in files .tpl.php.

Comment: When I logged into the admin panel, Drupla asked me to fix some errors and update files, after that the theme worked fine, but the main page and any other page says "Page not found", please advice. thanks